# Cpanel 11 - Time Zone

Tags: internet, cpanel

Please tell me where I can change the Time Zone of the Cpanel 11 from?
I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: What type of Cpanel? Like VPS, shared hosting, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VPS there should be "Server Time" within "Server Configuration".

If you're using Cpanel on some shared hosting service then I'd expect that to be a server wide setting, which cannot be changed by you. (One could temporarily set it for specific requests, like in PHP code, but only temporarily for *that* specific request then.)